# Create a csv file on SharePoint using VBA in O365

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have a macro that saves the result on a csv file on a network drive.

I want to change the destination to SharePoint.

I get

> error 52 incorrect name or file number.

I have the impression that the `Open *filename *For Output As #2` function does not work on SharePoint.

I checked the path to SharePoint. It looks correct.

I tried `Freefile()` but same bad result.

```vb
Sub Enreg() 

If NbEnregDV = 0 Then
    FileName = "\\xxx.sharepoint.com@ssl\sites\aaa\bbb\ccc\DV.csv" 
    Open FileName For Output As #2 
    LigneEntete = "data recorded" 
    Print #2, LigneEntete 
End If 

NbEnregDV = NbEnregDV + 1 

Machaine = "ABC;" & Matricule & ";" & Rubrique & ";;"

(etc. with the rest of other information to report in the file) 

Print #2, Machaine

End Sub
```

Comment: If you create the CSV as an excel file you can save that to Sharepoint (using the HTTP path).  There's no reliable way of using the `Open/Print` methods which work for local/network drives.  The only way I think is the sync the folder of interest to your local machine, and then write the file to the local sync destination.